# phpexcel get value if cell.index equals date.now

Tags: php, excel, foreach, phpexcel

I have a excel file with shedule. It's look like this:
[image]

I'm need to get cell value of current day as: **john 8**

I'm find to example, how to display xls file:

```
$dateD = date('d');
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("files.xls");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$aSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
foreach($aSheet->getRowIterator() as $row){
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    foreach($cellIterator as $cell){
        if ($cell->getCalculatedValue() == $dateD)
        echo $cell->getCalculatedValue(), ' | ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

But i can't get the value..

Answer (score 0):

I'm change code, and all work:

```
$intN = 0;
foreach($aSheet->getRowIterator() as $row){
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);
    // Iterate over the individual cells in the row
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $intN++;
        // Display information about the cell object
        if ($intN == $dateD){
            echo 'Cell ' , $cell->getCoordinate();
            echo '    is ' , $cell->getValue() , '<br />';
        }

    }
    $intN = 0;
}
```